# Problems Starting C Programs

Tags: c

I'm trying to execute the code below.  However, in eclispe, the program doesn't start until I enter a character and press enter.  For instance, if I hit run, I have to enter the number that will represent the age before it even asks me to enter my age.  I am wondering how to fix this.

```
int main() {

        int age;                          /* Need a variable... */

        printf( "Please enter your age" );  /* Asks for age */
        scanf( "%d", &age );                 /* The input is put in age */
        if ( age < 100 ) {                  /* If the age is less than 100 */
            printf ("You are pretty young!\n" ); /* Just to show you it works... */
        }
        else if ( age == 100 ) {            /* I use else just to show an example */ 
            printf( "You are old\n" );       
        }
        else {
            printf( "You are really old\n" );     /* Executed if no other statement is */
        }
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: That is not a full program; you are missing the headers. Pay heed to compiler warnings! And format your code properly.

Answer (score 4):

This is a pretty classic problem.  Your output stream has not been flushed.  Usually this happens after writing a newline (which you are not doing).  If you don't want a newline, you could issue a hard flush on standard out:

```
printf( "Please enter your age" );
fflush( stdout ); 
scanf( "%d", &age );
```

While I'm here, can I ask that you think about your commenting style?  Commenting every line of code is excessive.  Anybody who can read code understands what each line does, without needing a comment.  Put comments on their own line, and only to give an overview of several lines of code.  I prefer to see a quick overview of what I'm about to read so I know whether to bother reading it or not.

Comment: This was code from a tutorial, not my own. That's why the comments are excessive.

Comment: OK, that worked, but when I was looking up flush for C, I noticed that other  people at least get the first line they want to print to come up before they input anything.  For me, I have to input first before anything is printed in the program.  I have a feeling this could be an issue with how I've set up eclipse..

Comment: Are you saying that, even with `fflush`, you still don't see the text appear until after inputting?  Hopefully that's not what you're saying.  Differences in the flushing behaviour on terminals are normal.  Some terminal devices may flush every character.  Others flush when blocking on input.  Even flushing on newline isn't guaranteed, but most devices are set up that way.

Comment: It works perfectly with fflush.  Without fflush though (just as the code is written above), I can't get "Please enter your age" to appear directly after I press run in eclipse.  I have to input a number or character before that prints.  I was just wondering if this was regular for people who use C or not.

Comment: As I hinted about this being a common issue, the answer is yes: this does happen to people, and it's by design.  The I/O is buffered to make it more efficient.  Flushing the buffers will deliver their contents immediately, which is why it works.  Another option is to set the file stream to use no buffering with [`setvbuf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/setvbuf), but that's not a recommended solution to this problem.  You shouldn't turn off buffering just because you don't want to occasionally flush output.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help.